# Changing background color for WPF DataGrid cell depending on selection and value

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to achieve this: **When the user selects one or multiple cells in a DataGrid all duplicates should have their background color changed**.

I have this xaml

```
<Window x:Class="NotesOnFretboard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  Margin="12,110,12,29" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataTable dt = CreateDataTable();

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

So I populate the datagrid using a DataTable(10 rows, 25 columns).
In this datatable there are a number of duplicate values.

When the user selects one or multiple cells in a DataGrid all duplicates should have their background color changed!

Please Help!

// Anders

Comment: what are you binding to? what is the data structure? this could be much easier to reflect in the data structure.

Comment: The data structure is a ObservablCollection<ObservableCollection<Note>>. Where Note is a class Note { public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Octave { get; set; }
        public int Midi { get; set; }}  But since I haven't found any way of showing a list of lists in a DataGrid, I create a DataTable using the Name property. The duplicates will be in the Midi property

Answer (score 1):

you should be using triggers to achieve that
check out this comprehensive guide: [Styling Microsoft’s WPF datagrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your collection class so that it has a property to indicate whether it should be highlighted or not, then bind that property (through a converter) to the element property you want to change colour.
You'd could respond to a selection/click and change your ItemSource 'selected' property to true/false depending on whatever criteria you desire.

So something like:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="NoteList"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    HeadersVisibility="None"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding NoteList,Mode=OneWay}">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NoteDescription, Mode=OneWay}"
                             Background="{Binding NoteHighlighted, 
                                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColourConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```